# How do I use a variable declared inside a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This feels like a really basic question...that I cant find the answer for!  Just a basic jQuery click function:

```
$('button.one').click(function () {
    var selectorVal = 'one';
    $('div#one').slideDown('slow');
    $('div#two').slideUp('fast');
    return selectorVal;
}
```

How do I retrieve and output selectorVal outside the function?  Thanks so much!

Comment: just declare it outside of the function above it: var selectorVal; and inside of click, just use selectorVal = 'one';

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  What if the click handler didn't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Define variable outside the callback:

   ```
   var selectorVal;
   $('button.one').click(function (){
       selectorVal = 'one';
       $('div#one').slideDown('slow');
       $('div#two').slideUp('fast');
   });
   // somewhere here check for selectorVal value (if any)
   ```
2. (better) Use another callback:

   ```
   var doSomethingWithSelectorVal = function(selectorVal){
       // here do something with updated selectorVal value
   };
   $('button.one').click(function (){
       selectorVal = 'one';
       $('div#one').slideDown('slow');
       $('div#two').slideUp('fast');
       doSomethingWithSelectorVal(selectorVal);
   });
   ```

As I mentioned above, the second option is the better option, as using callback in this case is best suited.

Answer (score 1):

Should make selectorVal a global variable like this; no need to return anything with that function:

```
var selectorVal = '';
$('button.one').click(function(){
    selectorVal = 'one';
    $('div#one').slideDown('slow');
    $('div#two').slideUp('fast');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a global variable outside of the function and then just add a value to it inside the function (no need to return anything then)?

Answer (score 0):

depends on when you want access it
For example, if you sure that you access it after click function was executed, you can use such technique:

```
var outer_variable=null;
$('button.one').click(function () {
var selectorVal = 'one';
$('div#one').slideDown('slow');
$('div#two').slideUp('fast');
outer_variable=selectorVal;
return True;
}
```

Comment: by the way, it is a bad idea to return selectorVal. If there is possibility that value is 0, then your click wont be executed

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.
Something like

```
$('button.one').click(function () {
    window["var2"]="somedata";
}
```

After that, you will have access to the variable via the window but also on the global scope.
You can write `alert(var2)` outside of the function and it will work.